# Issue importing module pdftotext in Jupyter Notebook. "ImportError: DLL Load failed:"

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I am unable to import pdftotext library in Jupyter notebook, even though the library is installed. The OS being used is Windows. In order to resolve the issue "I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 version already installed in my system."

```
In [4]: import pdftotext 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b47658e7d4bc> in <module>
----> 1 import pdftotext 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: We do not work so well with screenshots. Please provide reasonable amount of code and details.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b47658e7d4bc> in <module>
----> 1 import pdftotext

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.